# Click image opens popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I wanna do is to click an image, which opens up a popup window with the image-URL in a textfield. Here is should be possible to change the URL and by that changing the image-URL.

Im very poor with javascript and thats why im asking for help.

**HTML**

```
<img src="#" onClick="changePicture();" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function changePicture() {
      var myPopup = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
}
```

Comment: Cool beans! But some code would be helpful. What have you tried?

Comment: I can give it a try but im pretty sure im going in the wrong direction. *Added some code

Comment: Maybe, but that is how you learn. By trying and failing until you get it right. I would suggest using http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/.

Comment: Also if you want to learn more JavaScript check out http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript.

Comment: Here is some explained:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It should be like a dialog/modal look

Comment: You should check out jQuery Dialogs, since you are using jQuery. Specifically, dialog forms, which contain inputs like you want. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: The problem is I want to send the current URL to the modal/dialog box and write it in there, furthermore it should be possible to change this URL

Comment: You should be able to send the URL to any modal/dialog. It really depends on what you choose to use. And then it is just a matter of coding it to work how you want. Really all a modal/ dialog is, is a div absolutely positioned in the center of the screen. It should be easy to pass info to something like that.

Comment: hey check my answer, i have used jquery dialog box ..

Comment: Yes, im looking into it right as we speak.

Comment: Thats the best suggested solution so far @DevendraSoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a example in jsfiddle..

when you will click on image it will open current image url in editing mode in pop up and you can change it.

```
function ChangeUrl(){ 
    var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
    var url = prompt("change image source",image1.src);   
    image1.src= url;
}
```

see working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/XUjAH/1094/

or i have created another jsfiddle for you, i have used jquery dialog box in place of prompt.

see this working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/9/

thanks

Comment: This is also very close to what im looking for. I just need it to be something else than a prompt window. Maybe a dialog box

Comment: Is it possible to close the dialog box if you click outside the window? And I misstold, it should not be inside a textbox :) It should just be a normal dialog box

Comment: Accept answer if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple to do. Make a image like so:

```
<img src="http://lorempizza.com/200/200/" onclick="change()" id="target">
```

And the function is very simple.

```
    function change(){
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    var current = target.src;
    var url = prompt("change address to:", current);
    target.src= url;
}
```

First, you define the variables. `var url` opens a prompt window that asks for the url. `var target` defines which image you want to change. And the last line changes `var target`'s src to the value of `var url`. `var current` gets the current url of the image and  adds the current url to the text-box.
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/aHwS8/157/)

Comment: This is somewhat what im looking for. Is it possible to make like a placeholder for the present URL in the prompt? And maybe change prompt to a modal/dialog box?

Comment: Yeah thats not very pleasent to look at. Is it possible to make the address inside the textfield?

Comment: Much better! Now I just need it to be a dialog box, but im going to look into that

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't fully understand your question, but you can use JavaScript/HTML to open a link in a new window with the following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('newWindow.html', 'newName', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">Click here</a>
```

That new document could house the view for your images (alternatively, you could just change the first argument of `open()` to the image itself), and from that new window your "textfield" to change is the url.

Comment: This is not what im looking for. I got an image and when i click on it, it should open a dialog box where the URL of the present image is in and furthermore it should be possible to change this URL

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

**IMG HTML:**

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('img').on("click",function(){
    var win = window.open();
    var url = $(this).attr("src");
    var html = $("body").html("<textarea>" + url +"</textarea>");
    $(win.document.body).html(html);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/HsTkf/10/

**If you are looking for a dialog:**

You could make your own and do something like this. This is still missing a few things such as a way to close it, proper positioning and what not. However, there are more advanced dialog libraries out there if this is what you are looking for.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" />

<div class="prompt"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('img').on("click",function(){
   var url = $(this).attr("src");
   $(".prompt").append("<textarea>" + url +"</textarea>");
   $(".prompt").addClass("show");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.prompt {
   display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:40%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HsTkf/21/

**Libraries:**

1. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
2. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
3. http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: The onClick event should not open a new tab, it should just open up a dialog box with a textfield and the URL within it

Comment: I have updated my answer with another idea for an alternative.

Comment: I dont appreciate the use of prompt, its really not functional for the job i want it to do. Im reading about the use of dialog boxes etc. atm. so maybe i'll find a solution myself. Thanks for trying tho

Comment: What do you mean by the "use of prompt"? Maybe update your question as to be more specific as to what you are looking for exactly.